# What is the oldest functional Launch Complex?

Tags: launch-site

[Space Launch Complex 17 at Cape Canaveral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_Canaveral_Air_Force_Station_Space_Launch_Complex_17) was demolished today (July 12, 2018). It was first put into operation in 1957 and was last used in 2011. I was surprised to learn it was 60 years old.

This makes me wonder what is the oldest remaining launch complex in regular operation for publicly announced general purpose rocket launches?

Comment: Do military facilities count? I believe some ballistic missile launch sites predate the earliest *space* launch sites, but the line between the two is often blurry...

Comment: I agree missile sites may pre-date, but much of that info is not public either. I specified "General Purpose Rockets" to keep the discussion focused on launch sites that are in public knowledge that launch publicly announced rockets which are commonly discussed on this site. I have no problem including a military launch site like those at Vandenberg if it allows publicly announced launches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think launch complex 1 at Baikonur should be a good candidate, its been in use for Soyuz launch vehicle derivatives since Sputnik 1 in 1957 and is still in regular use for manned and unmanned missions.